# PHP group repeated elements in array

Tags: php, arrays, repeat

How can the array be separated into groups of identical elements (concatenated chars).
For example, I have this array:

```
Array(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

and want to group all identical numbers in only one element, bringing the together with concatenation to get  something like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => 111
    [1] => 22
    [2] => 1
    )
```

Comment: Do you try did it by yourself?

Comment: Do you want all identical elements to be combined or only neighboring identical elements ?

Comment: Why [2] => 1, I wonder? Isn't `1` here identical to these `1`s before?

Comment: Perhaps he want all elements from the array, group by same value but seperate if they are not one after other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group all identical elements by concatenating them together (will not work for concatenating just the neighboring identical elements)

```
$arr = array (1,1,1,2,2,1);
$sum = array_count_values($arr);
array_walk($sum, function(&$count, $value) { 
  $count = str_repeat($value, $count); 
});
print_r($sum);
```

Output

> Array (
>       [1] => 1111
>       [2] => 22 )

Or for concatenating just the neighboring identical elements

```
$prev=null; 
$key=0; 
foreach ( $arr as $value ) { 
  if ($prev == $value){ 
    $res[$key] .= $value;
  } else { 
    $key++; 
    $res[$key] = $value; 
    $prev=$value; 
  } 
}
print_r($res);
```

Output

> Array (
>       [1] => 111
>       [2] => 22
>       [3] => 1 )

Answer (score 1):

Here two functions
1 will return

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

as output and second one will return

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1111
    [2] => 22
)
```

as output

```
$array = array(
    1,1,1,2,2,1
);

print_r(groupArray($array));

print_r(groupSame($array));


function groupArray($array){
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(!isset($temp[$value])){
            $temp[$value] = array();
        }
        array_push($temp[$value],$value);
    }
    return $temp;
}

function groupSame($array){
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(!isset($temp[$value])){
            $temp[$value] = "";
        }
        $temp[$value] .= $value;
    }
    return $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($Arrays as $key=>$val) {
    if (!isset($array[$i]))
       $array[$i]=$val;
    else if (!isset($mem) || $val==$mem)
       $array[$i]=10*$array[$i]+$mem;
   else
     $i++;
   $mem=$val;
}
?>
```

Comment: This might solve the current problem in hand but works only with integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1,1,1,2,2,1);
$start = "";
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $v){
    $v = (string)$v; 
    if($start==$v){
        $count = count($new_array) - 1;
        $val = $new_array[$count].$v;
        $new_array[$count] = $val;
    } else{
        $new_array[] = $v;
    }
    $start = $v;    
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

Tested and its working..

Output > `array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "111" [1]=> string(2) "22" [2]=> string(1) "1" }`